# YAML validation using JSON schema

Tags: javascript, validation, yaml, jsonschema, ajv

I am having a CI service that validates YAML files using JSON schema. The solution works by firstly converting the YAML to JSON using `js-yaml` and then by checking the schema using `ajv`

sample code:

```js
import { load } from 'js-yaml';
import { default as Ajv } from 'ajv';
import schema from '../../schema.json';

const ajv = new Ajv({
    strict: false
});

export const validate = (file: { content: string }) => {
    const parsed = load(file.content) as unknown;
    const valid = ajv.validate(schema, parsed);

    if (!valid) throw new Error(ajv.errorsText());
}
```

I would like to extend this solution to report back with the error Line and Column.
Do you know if there is a solution for this out there already? My GoogleFu let me down this time. The closest I got is <strike>[vscode XML plugin](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml)</strike> [vscode YAML plugin](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml) which seems to be tightly coupled with VS code :(

Comment: JSON Schema validators usually work on data that has already been parsed into code, so there is no line number information. The only exception I know of is https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschemaparse, which validates as it parses JSON. However that only parses JSON, not YAML.

Comment: It would be quite useful to take a .json file and a json pointer (that is a string in the form `/foo/0/bar/1/baz`) and return the line and column offsets where that location can be found in the file, but I do not know of any such tool/library, in any language.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers I am well aware of the process, hence I was hoping for some library, that could instruct the JSON parsed from YAML with some information that would allow for reverse lookup. For start, even line number would be better than nothing

Comment: @MarianBazalik Sorry if my comment sounded condescending. I just thought of another library that provides line numbers, but it also only supports JSON, https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-ajv-errors. You might be able to look at how they get line numbers from JSON Pointers and adapt it for YAML.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers :) no hard feelings. I will definitely have a look on better-ajv-erros. In the mentime I was looking into https://github.com/redhat-developer/yaml-language-server/blob/master/src/languageservice/services/yamlValidation.ts#L99 which is being used by vcsode plugin and I am strugling to understand how does the mapping between json error posision and yaml error position works :(